# Not abstract and does not override abstract method onCreateViewHolder using recyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created class which extends `RecycleView` for `Adapter` in `Android Studio` But it is showing the following error.

```
Error:(20, 8) error: HR_Vacancy_Adapter is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup,int) in Adapter

Error:(47, 31) error: onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup,int) in HR_Vacancy_Adapter cannot override onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup,int) in Adapter
return type HR_Vacancy_Adapter is not compatible with HR_Vacancy_Adapter.MyViewHolder
where VH is a type-variable:
VH extends ViewHolder declared in class Adapter
```

This my `Adapter`

```
public class HR_Vacancy_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HR_Vacancy_Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<HRVacancy> arr_hrvacancy;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tv_RAFno, tv_jobtitle, tv_postition, tv_Salary;
    public ImageView iv_companylogo;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        tv_RAFno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_RAFno);
        tv_jobtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_jobtitle);
        tv_postition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_postition);
        tv_Salary = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Salary);

        iv_companylogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_companylogo);
    }

}

public HR_Vacancy_Adapter(List<HRVacancy> arr_hrvacancy) {
    this.arr_hrvacancy = arr_hrvacancy;
}

@Override
public HR_Vacancy_Adapter onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_hr_vacancy, parent, false);
    return MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    HRVacancy hrvacancy = arr_hrvacancy.get(position);

    holder.tv_RAFno.setText(hrvacancy.getRafNo());
    holder.tv_jobtitle.setText(hrvacancy.getPost());
    holder.tv_postition.setText(hrvacancy.getPostition());
    holder.tv_Salary.setText(hrvacancy.getSalary());
    holder.iv_companylogo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_app);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arr_hrvacancy.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to return HR_Vacancy_Adapter.MyViewHolder from onCreateViewHolder()**.

Replace this:

```
@Override
public HR_Vacancy_Adapter onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_hr_vacancy, parent, false);
    return MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

With this:

```
@Override
public HR_Vacancy_Adapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_hr_vacancy, parent, false);
    return MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `onCreateViewHolder()` you need to return the `Viewholder` implementation.

Use the following code:

```
    @Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_hr_vacancy, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    return holder;
}
```